# Error : E/cr_PlatformSer-Internal: UsageReporting query failed

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, error-handling, runtime-error, razorpay-andoid-sdk

I want to connect ads in my app every five posts with one ads Continues,

This is my  Error: E/cr_PlatformSer-Internal: UsageReporting query failed

How to solve this problem any one tell  me